# How do I set a maximum length for text in pygame?

Tags: pygame

I've got a problem; I have boxes with text inside. The boxes have set sizes, but the text in them can chainge. I don't want the text going outside of them. Is there a build-in way or another way to get the text to stop at the edge of an box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you `blit` text on the screen you can check it dimensions with `get_rect()` method. And depending on it you can choose whether to display it or not. I made a simple example:

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

clock = pg.time.Clock()

win = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
FONT = pg.font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 20, 1, 1)


class Field(pg.Rect):

    def __init__(self, rect, text=None):
        super().__init__(rect)
        self.text = text

    def get_text(self):
        return self.text

    def check_bounds(self, text_rect):
        if text_rect.width > self.width:
            return False

        return True


def redraw(win):

    win.fill(pg.Color("white"))
    pg.draw.rect(win, pg.Color("green"), button_1, 1)
    text = FONT.render("Some textdasdsdsafdss", 1, pg.Color("red"))
    if button_1.check_bounds(text.get_rect()):
        win.blit(text, (button_1.x, button_1.y))
    else:
        text = FONT.render("Text is too long!", 1, pg.Color("red"))
        win.blit(text, (button_1.x, button_1.y))

    pg.display.update()


def main_loop(win):

    clock.tick(10)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            return False

    redraw(win)

    return True


button_1 = Field((100, 100, 170, 70))

while main_loop(win):
    pass


pg.quit()
```

I hope this answers your question

EDIT: Answer for the question in comments by OP

Trim the user input to fit the textbox, add the following:

```
if len(user_input) >= MAX_STRING_LEN:
        user_input = user_input[0:MAX_STRING_LEN]
    text = FONT.render(user_input, 1, pg.Color("red"))
```

`user_input` is the string you loaded from the file and the `MAX_STRING_LEN` is a constant. If you have textboxes with different sizes you will need more constants.
In this case you do not need `else` part which blits "text is too long".

Comment: I am not sure why, but it seems that syntax highlighting is not displaying properly, at least on my screen

Comment: This answered my question partly. Is there a way to make the text appear only partly, so that only text that does fit in the box is shown?

Comment: I have an idea how that could work but I need to know how do you get the user input from the box

Comment: It's a name that is loaded from a file. It doesn't chainge. The name is loaded into a string.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question; where can I add the part that crops the text? Above or in a specific place?

Comment: Glad I helped. Well, I do not know how your code looks like, I would probably put it in a function or a method which takes one `string` parameter and returns the (trimmed) string. And then call the function when I want to blit on the screen. Also depending on the file size I would load all the strings into the list and based on the textbox ID call the funtcion and pass it a `list[ID]` string.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I'll take your advice and make a function.

Comment: You are welcome, and if you have more questions I am happy to assist